# alternative solution to anagram algo question

Tags: javascript, algorithm, counter, anagram

I've pasted the practice problem I'm solving as a photo below. I have one answer that works right, but I tried switching it up and I'm not sure why the alternative answer doesn't work. Would appreciate any explanations, thanks!

[image]

my solution that works

```
var string1 = "somethingb"
var string2 = "omesnigthr"

function validAn(string1,string2)
{
    let obj1 = {}
    let obj2 = {}

    if (string1.length !== string2.length){
        return false
    }
    for(let char of string1){ 
        obj1[char]= (obj1[char] || 0) + 1
    }
    for(let char of string2){
        obj2[char]= (obj2[char] || 0) + 1
    }
    for(var val in obj1){
        if(!(val in obj2)){
            return false
        }
        if(obj2[val] !== obj1[val]){
            return false
        }
    }
 return true
}
```

my solution that doesn't work

```
var string1 = "somethingb"
var string2 = "omesnigthr"

function validAn(string1,string2)
{
    let obj1 = {}
    let obj2 = {}

    if (string1.length !== string2.length){
        return false
    }
    for(let char of string1){ 
        obj1[char]= (obj1[char] || 0) + 1
    }
    for(let char of string2){
        obj2[char]= (obj2[char] || 0) + 1
    }
    for(var val in obj1){
        if(val in obj2) && (obj2[val] == obj1[val])){
            return true
        }
    }
return true
}
```

Comment: The `==` in the last for loop should be `!=`.

Comment: And there should be an `else return false` to that last if statement.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? Trace through a simple example by hand (for example `validAn("a", "b")`) and see what happens and why it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

In your second solution that doesn't work, you always return true. In the third for loop, you should check if both objects have the key with same value, and if not return false :

```js
var string1 = "somethingb"
var string2 = "omesnigthr"

function validAn(string1,string2)
{
    let obj1 = {}
    let obj2 = {}

    if (string1.length !== string2.length){
        return false
    }
    for(let char of string1){ 
        obj1[char]= (obj1[char] || 0) + 1
    }
    for(let char of string2){
        obj2[char]= (obj2[char] || 0) + 1
    }
    for(var val in obj1){
        if(!(val in obj2) || (obj2[val] !== obj1[val])){
            return false
        }
    }
return true
}

console.log(validAn(string1, string2));
```